# return specific properties from array of objects into new object

Tags: javascript

I've an array of objects, what I want is to copy all the objects from that, but with specific properties not all the properties.
like for example I've this object named `cart`

```
cart = [
    { id: 1, name: 'makeup', price: 200, qty: 1 },
    { id: 2, name: 'gloves', price: 300, qty: 2 },
    { id: 3, name: 'sanitizer', price: 400, qty: 3 },
    { id: 4, name: 'book', price: 100, qty: 1 },
    { id: 5, name: 'hairs', price: 250, qty: 4 },
    { id: 6, name: 'soap', price: 50, qty: 5 },
    { id: 7, name: 'shampoo', price: 700, qty: 1 },
  ]
```

and I want to extract only the `id` and `qty` attributes to a new array of objects.
How do I do this.
I already tried
`products=cart.map(prod=>prod.id, prod.qty)`
but this doesn't seems to be working.
Thanks in advance to helping hands

Comment: `cart.map(c => ({id: c.id, qty: c.qty}))`

Comment: have you looked at the [documentation for Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)?

Comment: `cart.map(({id, qty}) => ({id, qty}))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `Array.prototype.map()` or `Array.prototype.reduce()` over the entire array and only return the values you want.

```js
const cart = [
  { id: 1, name: 'makeup', price: 200, qty: 1 },
  { id: 2, name: 'gloves', price: 300, qty: 2 },
  { id: 3, name: 'sanitizer', price: 400, qty: 3 },
  { id: 4, name: 'book', price: 100, qty: 1 },
  { id: 5, name: 'hairs', price: 250, qty: 4 },
  { id: 6, name: 'soap', price: 50, qty: 5 },
  { id: 7, name: 'shampoo', price: 700, qty: 1 },
]
console.log( cart.map( elem => ({id:elem.id, qty : elem.qty})))
```

Comment: is there any way during this process I can rename my variable `qty` to `quantity` ?

Comment: console.log( cart.map( elem => ({id:elem.id, quantity: elem.qty})))

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate and return only the desired properties.

```js
cart = [
    { id: 1, name: 'makeup', price: 200, qty: 1 },
    { id: 2, name: 'gloves', price: 300, qty: 2 },
    { id: 3, name: 'sanitizer', price: 400, qty: 3 },
    { id: 4, name: 'book', price: 100, qty: 1 },
    { id: 5, name: 'hairs', price: 250, qty: 4 },
    { id: 6, name: 'soap', price: 50, qty: 5 },
    { id: 7, name: 'shampoo', price: 700, qty: 1 },
  ]
  
const newcart = cart.map(item => {
  return {id: item.id, qty: item.qty}
  });

console.log(newcart)
```

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it correct.

When using arrow functions without the brackets, whatever is put after the arrow function is returned.
So your code could look like this:

```
const products = cart.map(({ id, qty }) => ({ id, qty }));
```

We destructure the object in the arrow function and return it as a new object.

Make sure to have the round brackets around the value that you return. Otherwise javascript will see it as the body of a function instead of an object that is returned.

Answer (score 1):

You can update your `.map()` method like this to acheive the desired result:

```js
const cart = [{id:1,name:"makeup",price:200,qty:1},{id:2,name:"gloves",price:300,qty:2},{id:3,name:"sanitizer",price:400,qty:3},{id:4,name:"book",price:100,qty:1},{id:5,name:"hairs",price:250,qty:4},{id:6,name:"soap",price:50,qty:5},{id:7,name:"shampoo",price:700,qty:1}];

const products = cart.map(({id, qty}) => ({ id, quantity: qty }))
console.log(products)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: is there any way during this process I can rename my variable `qty` to `quantity` ?

Comment: Yes, you can simply do `cart.map(({id, qty}) => ({ id, quantity: qty }))`. I have updated the demo also. Hope it helps!